# What is "the local directory"? Why is it different from "Local" on my PC?

Tags: python, module, environment-variables

*" You can use the environment variable PYTHONPATH to specify additional directories to look for modules like this: "*

```
PYTHONPATH=/f1 python mymodule.py
```

It's said that this executes mymodule.py, and enables the script to load modules from the f1 directory, **as well as the local directory.**

I thought that it was " Local Disk (C:) > Users > (MyFolder) > AppData > **Local** ", so that if I import some module, it's being executed from "Local" just because **all** my  .py  files are saved in "Local" (including f1). So if the script loads modules from the f1 directory **AND** the local directory, then "Local" and "the local directory" are not the same. Why not? What is "the local directory"? Where to find it?

P.S. That might be a stupid question, but I'm a very beginner in programming.

Comment: I assume "local directory" means "directory where the script lives" (which is the directory that gets added to the search path implicitly).

Comment: Sorry @Jason - you need 3k rep to cast close votes - until then, you should be able to "flag" the post, which is similar.

Comment: @toby gotcha yeah that’s what I ended up doing after not being able to find a ‘vote button’

Answer (score 1):

Python will search for modules in the folder where the file which has the `import` statement is located. I assume the quote in your question refers then to the folder in which the current python file is saved. Take into account the folder may be different for each of the files imported into the interpreter.

Take into account that each path in `PYTHONPATH` must be absolute, so either `/f1` is a folder in a linux root, or you should use a folder like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:/path/to/lib
```

Also, the syntax you write above may only work in linux shell, and windows cmd.exe may have a different mechanism to set up environment variables like `PYTHONPATH`:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:/path/to/lib
python mymodule.py
```